# Nginx location for one letter

Tags: nginx

How to properly make the **location** and **rewrite** for query type:

Request:

```
site.com/a/?f=qwerty
```

rewrite to:

```
/a/?f=qwerty
```

Request:

```
site.com/b/?g=qwerty
```

rewrite to:

```
/b/?g=qwerty
```

Request:

```
site.com/anyshorttext/?h=qwerty
```

rewrite to:

```
/special/?h=qwerty
```

I applied these solutions:

```
server {

        location ~ /a/?(.*)$ {

            rewrite ^/([-\w]+) /a/?m=$1 break;

            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

                location ~ \.php$ {
                        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                }
        }

        location ~ /b/?(.*)$ {

            rewrite ^/([-\w]+) /b/?m=$1 break;

            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

                location ~ \.php$ {
                        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                }
        }

        location ~* ^/[a-zA-Z0-9/_$/]+$ {

            rewrite ^/([-\w]+) /special/?h=$1 break;

            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

                location ~ \.php$ {
                    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
                }
        }
  }
```

But in this case the requests are forwarded to **/special/** only

Thank you.

Comment: Anything after the `?` is the query string and is not part of the normalised URI used by the `rewrite` and `location` directives. In your requirements: `//site.com/a/?f=qwerty` to `/a/?f=qwerty` is a NOP.

Comment: Your examples imply the query string does not change for each case. If that's true, I've got a solution for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples imply that the query string does not change for each case. If that's so, you could try the following:

```
map $uri $special_query {
    # $special_query will be true, for paths like: //site.com/xyz/?stuff
    ~^/[^/]+/$ $query_string;
}

server {
    location / {
        if ($special_query) {
            return 301 "/special/?$query_string";
        }
    }

    # these locations will override the default / location
    location = /a/ {}
    location = /b/ {}
    location = /special/ {}
}
```

This solution uses neither regex locations nor rewrites both of which can add unnecessary complexity to your configuration and disrupt the natural nginx flow. (See scaleable configuration by nginx author Igor Sysoev: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YWRYbLKsS0I)

Comment: Thank you Cole Tierney for your responsiveness. I show my complete configuration. Please look again. Your previous reply did not help me. Thank you.

Comment: I tested my solution before posting. If you tried to combine my solution with regex locations it will likely not work. My suggestion would be remove all regex locations and avoid rewrites if possible. If you must use regular expressions, put them in a map or wrap them with prefix locations to reduce their impact on the rest of your config. Check the video I posted for details.